# GETPIVOTDATA #REF Error

Tags: excel, pivot

Hi I have this pivot table layout like this:

Sum of Received Quantity        MFG2 Month
MFG2 Year   Hard failure    1   2   3   4
1970    NO  7
    YES 21
1971    YES 1
1972    YES
1981    NO  1
    YES         1
1982    NO          1
    YES     2
1990    YES
1991    YES
1992    YES
1993    YES         1

My problem is that when I try to get data with getpivotdata (GETPIVOTDATA("Received Quantity";$A$15;"Hard failure";"NO";"MFG2 Month";8;"MFG2 Year";2005)) I receive a #REF error, any suggestion?